# Lot of UDP requests lost in UDP server with Netty

Tags: multithreading, udp, threadpool, nio, netty

I wrote a simple UDP Server with Netty that simply prints out in logs the messages (frames) received. To do that, I created a simple frame decoder decoder and a simple message handler. I also have a client that can send multiple requests sequentially and/or in parallel.

When I configure my client tester to send for example few hundred of requests sequentially with a small delay between them, my server written with Netty receives them all properly. But at the moment I increase the number of simultaneous requests in my client (100 for example) coupled with sequential ones and few repeats, my server starts loosing many requests. When I send 50000 requests for example, my server only receives about 49000 when only using the simple ChannelHandler that prints out the received message.

And when I add the simple frame decoder (that prints out the frame and copies it into another buffer) in front of this handler, the server only handles half of the requests!!

I noticed that no matter the number of workers I specify to the created NioDatagramChannelFactory, there is always one and only one thread that handles the requests (I am using the recommended Executors.newCachedThreadPool() as the other parameter).

I also created another similar simple UDP Server based on the DatagramSocket coming with the JDK and it handles every requests perfectly with 0 (zero) lost!! When I send 50000 requests in my client (with 1000 threads for example), I received 50000 requests in my server.

Am I doing something wrong while configuring my UDP server using Netty? Or maybe Netty is simply not designed to support such load?? Why is there only one thread used by the given Cached Thread Pool (I noticed that only one thread and always the same is used by looking in JMX jconsole and in by checking the thread name in the output logs)? I think if more threads where used as expected, the server would be able to easily handle such load because I can do it without any problem when not using Netty!

**See my initialization code below:**

```
...

lChannelfactory = new NioDatagramChannelFactory( Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), nbrWorkers );
lBootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap( lChannelfactory );

lBootstrap.setPipelineFactory( new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline()
    {
        ChannelPipeline lChannelPipeline = Channels.pipeline();
        lChannelPipeline.addLast( "Simple UDP Frame Dump DECODER", new SimpleUDPPacketDumpDecoder( null ) );            
        lChannelPipeline.addLast( "Simple UDP Frame Dump HANDLER", new SimpleUDPPacketDumpChannelHandler( lOuterFrameStatsCollector ) );            
        return lChannelPipeline;
    }
} );

bindChannel = lBootstrap.bind( socketAddress );

...
```

**And the content of the decode() method in my decoder:**

```
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext iCtx, Channel iChannel, ChannelBuffer iBuffer) throws Exception
{
    ChannelBuffer lDuplicatedChannelBuffer = null;
    sLogger.debug( "Decode method called." );

    if ( iBuffer.readableBytes() < 8 ) return null;
    if ( outerFrameStatsCollector != null ) outerFrameStatsCollector.incrementNbrRequests();

    if ( iBuffer.readable() ) 
    {        
        sLogger.debug( convertToAsciiHex( iBuffer.array(), iBuffer.readableBytes() ) );                     
        lDuplicatedChannelBuffer = ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer( iBuffer.readableBytes() );            
        iBuffer.readBytes( lDuplicatedChannelBuffer );
    }

    return lDuplicatedChannelBuffer;
}
```

**And the content of the messageReceived() method in my handler:**

```
public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext iChannelHandlerContext, final MessageEvent iMessageEvent) throws Exception
{
    ChannelBuffer lMessageBuffer = (ChannelBuffer) iMessageEvent.getMessage();
    if ( outerFrameStatsCollector != null ) outerFrameStatsCollector.incrementNbrRequests();

    if ( lMessageBuffer.readable() ) 
    {        
        sLogger.debug( convertToAsciiHex( lMessageBuffer.array(), lMessageBuffer.readableBytes() ) );            
        lMessageBuffer.discardReadBytes();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that UDP has no delivery guarantees right?

Comment: Yes, I know that there is no such delivery guarantees, but my load tests are done locally and I do not loose anything with my simple server using DatagramSocket instead of Netty stuff. I am also currently analyzing the requests with WireShark to validate that nothing is lost in one case (without netty) and that packets are lost when using netty.

Comment: @The4Summers If you can see that packets are being lost with Netty, Netty isn't processing the incoming packets quickly enough, or you aren't, so the socket receive buffer is filling, so incoming packets are being discarded, having nowhere else to go. Speed up your receiving or slow down your sending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not properly configured the ConnectionlessBootstrap instance.

1. You have to configure followings with optimum values.

   SO_SNDBUF size, SO_RCVBUF size and a ReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory

   ```
   lBootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576);

   lBootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576);

   lBootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", 
    new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory(MIN_SIZE, INITIAL_SIZE, MAX_SIZE));
   ```

   check DefaultNioDatagramChannelConfig class for more details.
2. The pipeline is doing everything using the Netty work thread. If
   worker thread is overloaded, it will delay the selector event loop
   execution and there will be a bottleneck in reading/writing the
   channel. You have to add a execution handler as following in the
   pipeline. It will free the worker thread to do its own work.

   ```
   ChannelPipeline lChannelPipeline = Channels.pipeline();

   lChannelPipeline.addFirst("execution-handler", new ExecutionHandler(
     new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(16, 1048576, 1048576));

   //add rest of the handlers here
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the buffer size options! However, regarding the execution handler, I tried it after this post and, yes it help a bit, but I was still loosing half of the requests when a decoder and an handler is used. I'm sure that increasing the buffer will help lot more.

Comment: However, I still not understand why we must specify a thread pool executor and a number of workers when instantiating the NioDatagramChannelFactory class if they are never used!!??

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Thread pool executors are used to create worker threads in NioDatagramChannel pipelines. One worker thread can be assigned to a DatagramChannel to do non blocking read/write. If your application is listening on more than one port, many worker threads (default is cpu size * 2) will be created and assigned to  DatagramChannel  in a round robin fashion. If you want to  have more worker threads, you can specify in NioDatagramChannelFactory constructor.

Comment: Still I can not believe that the netty app is losing packets! Are you sure that your decoder is working properly?, Why don't you use a frame decoder comes with netty (FixedLengthFrameDecoder, LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder ..) and count the number of messages in your handler?

Comment: is this line correct?  if ( iBuffer.readableBytes() < 8 ) return null;

Comment: Finally, adding these buffer size options help a bit, but I still loosing frames. My real implementation is more complex than the example I shown in this question. We have implemented our own protocol over UDP and we have a special decoder to validate we have a complete and valide frame (preamble, command, length, crc, etc.), and the minimum frame lenght is 8 bytes (this is why in my example I kept this validation).   Yes, I could try with a fixedLengthFrameDecoder since I know the max size of my frame is 1088 bytes.

Comment: I also had a similar request loosing issue. After some investigation it turns out that [Netty UDP don't support multi-threading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514469/threads-not-executing-concurrently-in-netty-udp-server). So during high load time, some of the requests were silently dropped. After adding custom Executor pool to process the requests, packet dropping issue was also solved.